# How to check if `comment_meta` exists before inserting the comment?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, email, wp-insert-post, comment-meta

I am inserting comments via `wp_insert_comment` and while doing so I am adding email replies only. Now, I want to check if the comment is already present or not before inserting and if does exist do not perform `wp_insert_comment`.
Here, is my code:

```
 // Here, we insert the replies as comment to their parent email. 
            if ((!empty($mail['header']->references )) && (preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->references, '@',true))) == (preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->references, '@',true))))     
                {
                  //echo htmlentities($mail['header']->message_id);

                $posts = get_posts( array(
                    'post_type'  => 'post-type',
                    'meta_key'   => 'ticket_id',
                    'meta_value' => preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->references, '@',true)),
                ) );
                    
            if ( ! empty( $posts )   ) {
                $comment_array = array(
                    'comment_content' => $mail['body'],
                    'comment_post_ID' => $posts[0]->ID,
                    'comment_author'  => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
                    'comment_author_email' => preg_replace('~[<>]~', '', strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<')),
                    'comment_type'  => 'email_replies',
                    'comment_date'  => $mail['header']->Date,
                    'comment_meta'  => preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->message_id, '@',true)),
                );
                   wp_insert_comment($comment_array);
            }
            }
```

I am a still beginner so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to fix the `comment_meta` value. It should be an **array** of meta key and value pairs, and not just the meta value.

So give the meta a key (or name), e.g. `message_id`, and then do something like so:

```php
'comment_meta' => array(
    'message_id' => preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->message_id, '@',true)),
),
```

Now to check if a comment already exists by a specific meta, you can use [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) and the meta query, just like you did using `get_posts()`.

So for example:

```php
$comment_exists = (bool) get_comments( array(
    'type'       => 'email_replies',
    'meta_key'   => 'message_id',
    'meta_value' => preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->message_id, '@',true)),
    'count'      => true, // this means we're retrieving the number of comments only
) );

if ( ! $comment_exists ) {
    $posts = get_posts( ... );

    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        // insert the comment
    }
}
```

And BTW, you should assign the above `preg_replace()`'s value to a variable and then use it with the `comment_meta` and `meta_value` above.

Comment: Ok I will do as you said. But what to do inside this:  `if ( ! $comment_exists ) {
    $posts = get_posts( ... ); this`

Comment: Use the same code in the question.. i.e. `if ((!empty($mail['header']->references )) && (preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->references, '@',true))) == (preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->references, '@',true)))) { put the example in my answer here. the rest is the same as the one in your post/question }` Make sense?

Comment: Nothing happens. The problem here might be with `references` & `message_id` because reply emails have both `references` and `message_id`.

Comment: Let me see your code first - post it on Pastebin. But if you've used the correct meta key/value when inserting a comment and checking if there's an existing comment with the same meta, then the `$comment_exists` above would give you the correct results.

Comment: I have pasted all the code:
https://pastebin.com/DddmzpU5

Comment: Thanks, but I actually agreed that the email replies might have the same `message_id` meta value, so you can try adding other conditions in your `get_comments()` args.

Comment: email replies have a unique `message_id` but their `reference_id` is the same as the `message_id` of their parent email. So, that's what I did. I checked if the  `reference_id` is equal to `message_id` then insert the comment to the post that is the parent email.

Comment: You can try to generate an MD5 hash of the reply's/comment's content (but regarding the specificity, it's up to you, e.g. you may want to combine the content and the author's email) and add it as a comment meta, then check if there's an existing comment with that hash.

Comment: But the hash part is just my suggestion and nothing specific to WordPress, hence I didn't update my answer.

Comment: Ok, no need to worry. I just did your code from fresh and now it is working.
I have also pasted my code here: https://pastebin.com/DddmzpU5 for you to check.
I am really grateful for your support and I think I can learn a lot from you. If there is any way we could get connected it would be nice.

Comment: I'm glad I could help (and I'll check your code later..). As for getting connected, let's just do it via comments like this when you have another question - a reminder, though, make sure your question is on-topic.. :)